# A DRY approach for multiple excepts

Tags: python, error-handling, dry

Let's assume we have a following code:

```
try:
    whatever
except ValueError:
    something1
except (IndexError, KeyError):
    something2
except KeyBoardInterrupt:
    something3
except Exception:
    something4
else:  # no error
    something5
finally:
    finalize
```

So we have multiple excepts. Do we have any else-antipod that will suit DRY approach, so this will be executed only if any error happened?

For example, we want to set some error variable/flag or log the error, but apart of that execute different except logic without writing a method/func `except_logic()` and calling it in every except.

Comment: As a title, might I suggest something like, say, "*Performing an operation if any exception handler from a chain triggers*"? Right now it's not obvious what you're asking for without clicking through.

Comment: BTW, you aren't specifying whether the shared logic needs to come before or after your various `something`s. If it doesn't matter, that suggests a solution.

Comment: like an example: I want to log the exception but process it differently

Comment: If you want to do the same thing for any error, *and* specific things for specific errors, have *one* `except` and inspect the exception with `isinstance`/`match` to add specific handling?

Comment: @deceze probably this way, thanks, because for now I cannot imagine better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach would be to use a catch-all exception handler to handle any exception with the same shared logics, but then reraise the exception in a nested exception handler for type-specific exception handling logics:

```
try:
    something()
except Exception as e:
    log_exception(e)
    try:
        raise
    except ValueError:
        process_valueerror(e)
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        process_indexerror_keyerror(e)
    # more shared logics can run here after type-specific logics
    post_processing(e)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/vlEXtu

You can also use @deceze's solution in the comments by explicitly testing the type of the exception with `if` statements instead:

```
try:
    something()
except Exception as e:
    log_exception(e)
    if isinstance(e, ValueError):
        process_valueerror(e)
    elif isinstance(e, (IndexError, KeyError)):
        process_indexerror_keyerror(e)
    # more shared logics can run here after type-specific logics
    post_processing(e)
```

This saves 2 lines by not having to reraise the exception but at the same time it adds the boilerplate of calling `isinstance(e, ...)` for each addtional error handler, so it comes down to the personal taste which approach you prefer.

Comment: yes, this one, but instead of raising - using isinstance. I will edit and accept

Comment: edit failed. (visible only to me). well edit is better

Comment: ```try:
    something()
except Exception as e:
    log_exception(e)
    if isinstance(e, ValueError):
        process_valueerror(e)
    if isinstance(e, (IndexError, KeyError)):
        process_indexerror_keyerror(e)
    # more shared logics can run here after type-specific logics
    post_processing(e)```

Comment: It's a matter of taste which one is better in this case. Your requested edit is based on the solution @deceze offered in the comment. I like my solution slightly better only because a nest `try-except` block makes the code's intention clearer IMHO since the `try-except` construct is dedicated to error handling by the language. Granted you save 2 lines by using the `if..isinstance` approach, but you also have to repeat the boilerplate of a call to `isinstance(e, ...)` for each additional error handler, so I would update my answer with both solutions included instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow DRY best, you can also use `except*`. It is set up such that **multiple `except*`** run.

- `except*` is to switch-case, as
- `except` is to if-else

See here for more details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#except-star

To use it, you just need to create a new Exception class to be handled. (In the example below, I use "Common"). Then you do a bit of "pre-processing" first:

```py
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup("eg", [Common(...), ValueError(...)])
except* Common as err:
    do_some_common_processing(err)
except* ValueError:
    something1
except* (IndexError, KeyError):
    something2
except* KeyBoardInterrupt:
    something3
except* Exception:
    something4
else:  # no error
    something5
finally:
    finalize
```

You can't mix together except and except*.

---

**Edit:** it's worth emphasizing that you need to raise an `ExceptionGroup` to do this. Additionally, as pointed out by @blhsing, something like `Common` needs to be explicitly given in that group.

- If you are writing your own `raise`, or if the code already raises a compatible `ExceptionGroup`, you might find this approach beneficial.
- If your code does not raise an `ExceptionGroup`, you are probably better off using another approach.

Comment: Probably worth briefly mentioning that this is a Python >=3.11 feature.

Comment: The problem here is that you have to raise `Common` explicitly. If an exception is raised by code you do not own, `Common` would not be raised, and the common handler would not be executed.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you do not own the code, or do not expect an `ExceptionGroup` to be raised, you would need to catch and reraise to make this suggestion work. I would argue that that would be overengineering for most purposes -- you would be better off to use one of the other recommended approaches if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for processing order you may do the following:

```
error_state = True

try:
    print("Try")  # try raising here to see 'Error occurred'
except ...:
    ...
else:
    print("Else")
    error_state = False
finally:
    if error_state:
        print("Error occurred")
```

But it's better to do (more readable)

```
def process_exception(e: Exception):
    # if isinstance(e, type1): ... and so on
    ...


try:
    print("Try")
except Exception as e:
    ...
    # do something common
    ...
    process_exception(e)
```

Comment: this is actually what I told as `except_logic()`. It is not really comfortable, I think a comment to do one except and that use isinstance is the best suitable for a DRY for now